# Google Search Console is reporting an hAtom error for every page on my site

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data, error, crawl-errors

Whenever I publish a new article to my site, Google reports a new error by default in Search Console.

[image: hAtom Error]

I don't see what the issue is.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hatom is apart of [Hentry](http://microformats.org/wiki/hentry) which is a microformat for structured data and by default comes enabled in WordPress. It is a common occurrence that WP themes especially those that are 'free' have one or more issues with markup in relation to Hentry, many developers do not test their themes with [Google's rich snippet testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

*You have 3 choices to fix the issue:*

1. Contact your template designer or change theme.
2. Edit the template files and try to attempt to fix the issue yourself.
3. Disable Hentry.

It's a issue experienced by thousands of webmasters all over the globe and you should have no issue finding out further information and solutions to fix the issue.